# How to save jenkins builds into workspace by writing jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am practicing Jenkins pipeline by reading pipeline syntax documentation, as I was going through the flow I got a question that "How to save jenkins builds into workspace by writing jenkins declarative pipeline"

Answer (score 0):

All jenkins builds are saved in `jobs` folder inside your "Jenkins Home" directory.
Example: "jobs->jobname->builds" 
[image]

Comment: @Aravind can you accept this answer if this works for you

Comment: Yes @Altaf, Jenkins saves it's builds in BUILD Directory right. But my question is when I was writing Pipeline, is there any way to activate workspace by writing pipeline.

Comment: @Aravind , if you mean you want to access the workspace in the pipeline then just use :``def Workspace=env.WORKSPACE ``
``println(Workspace)``